# How to make toast when Facebook ShareButton is grayed out because app is missing?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-sharing

I have included the Facebook `ShareButton` in my Android App, as follows:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
     .setBitmap(map)
     .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
     .addPhoto(photo)
     .build();
mShareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

I notice that if my phone doesn't have the Facebook App installed, the `ShareButton` is grayed out. If I click it, as one would expect, nothing happens. I would like a `Toast` to pop up in this case, to inform the user that they need to have the Facebook App installed to use the share feature. How can I do so? I tried adding:

```
if (!mShareButton.isEnabled()) {
     mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view)
         {
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Requires Facebook app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });
}
```

However, this didn't do anything when I click the grayed out button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this almost seems like it never sets the listener. And you'll want that in place regardless of its state. Move that `if` inside `onClick` and clearly handle the conditions.

```
// pseudo
button.setListener {
    if button.isEnabled doFacebookThing()
    else showToast()
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think it'll listen at all while disabled, unless you subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can explicitly check if the App is installed or not...

```
public boolean isFBInstalled() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo("FB APP PACKAGE NAME", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            isInstalled = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            isInstalled = false;
        }
        return isInstalled;
    }
```

then in the onClick of Share button simply check if the app is installed or not like below -

```
        if(isFBInstalled) {
            doFbStuff();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Facekook App not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```